# I tried to swap my sd with extsd

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

I used es file manager and went to file vold.fstab and changed something wrong now I can't access my external sdcard or my file manager or my settings device storage. My phone is screwed up I cant figure out how to change it back to normal. I have the Samsung galaxy exhibit. Sght599. PLEASE HELP ME!

Answer (score 0):

Restoring phone to factory settings is the easiest way. Tough way is to search on net for a valid vold.fstab file, which can be generally found in custom built ROMs.